# Error in AR model for some time series in r

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive-models

I have a few time series and I am trying to find the Autoregressive correlation of them using AIC method. However, for a few of the time series, they keep producing an error. Below is one of these time series:

```
ts = c(NA, -5.29677810703267, 20.924713499646, -12.9426706411937, 
-59.8965047914283, 28.0656367870643, -14.0538201675938, 71.7475500827194, 
-26.5278267238737, 21.1224751507487, -8.29911855529105, 4.20981789612903, 
1.6517102431311, -20.9710157761627, 9.34406557636963, -0.400619961149677, 
24.7973533494015, -2.05958875385488, NA, NA, 8.06434983475257, 
48.0120034574876, -120.083129642974, 42.781376271489, -24.3920530610003, 
-40.6009919023201, -9.84301451434842, -30.115695158963, 43.5833919019582, 
13.2566724065373, 32.9065720928964, 24.5355166991576, 19.1459319634431, 
-5.259756376125, -21.6791225814247, 43.8902590856663, -68.5491856367301, 
-8.99503101049164, -66.4448512974963, 27.1037792403782, NA, 68.2060957432526, 
21.7646331844968, -19.6686755968915, 15.9085951372099, -32.5011288750771, 
1.1045781043698, 44.7281418136726, -72.6280120090465, -37.9614576256654, 
NA, 61.4494787118858, 56.1987121423001, -1.01964326869703, 96.7968382170166, 
-63.3494176624368, NA, -44.5204385643568, -126.540352110579, 
124.48669993052, -21.4368567029375, 10.6914037271706, 34.8739069589663, 
-74.8869212694283, -43.588655219891, 17.7711308457003, -4.80513733453226, 
-23.3150340224666, -33.7561334799807, 105.873990031048, NA, 66.3576089112204, 
-23.7840442433912, 70.1552285230281, -71.8221470513996, -57.7137452285522, 
66.4828597296925, 7.77009356145655, -62.849617995138, -35.3738492019689, 
27.1998256790859, -76.1261676138515, 69.6505966573409, -9.46745576921455, 
54.5221008446041, -7.37830776308098, 22.8337441458523, -28.8393176904739, 
-52.3950675339376, 42.1689203535835)

> ar(x, aic = TRUE, na.action=na.pass)

Error in if (order) coefs[order, seq_len(order)] else numeric() : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In log(var.pred) : NaNs produced
2: In if (order) coefs[order, seq_len(order)] else numeric() :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Does anyone know whats the issue?

Comment: It's probably the NA values in your timeseries. If I do a test and I replace the NAs with 0 the function ar(x, na.action=na.pass) returns ok.

Comment: The na.action = na.pass argument deals with the NAs. It works for my other timeseries with NAs

Comment: Ok - I'm not sure what the issue is then. Your code above failed for me but I note a slightly different error: "Error in ar.yw.default(x, aic = aic, order.max = order.max, na.action = na.action,  : 
  NAs in 'x'"

Comment: Hmmm thats odd....

Comment: Oops - I have a couple of versions of R installed. If I switch to my latest version I get the same message as you.

Comment: If I swap out the NAs in your ts for 0s, the ar() call works ok. Here are my version details. R version 3.5.1; stats version 3.5.1. Hope that helps.

Comment: But I can't switch out NAs for 0s as they mean different things. A 0 is a value, whereas a NA means 'nothing'.

Comment: That's fair. However it might indicate that the NAs are the cause of the error and give you an avenue to investigate.

Comment: You could use `arima(ts, order=c(1,0,0))`. No idea about the error.

Comment: It is weird, seems a bug, because this: `ar(c(rnorm(10), NA, rnorm(10)), na.action = na.pass, aic=T)`, works.